# RANK() with PIVOT() - limit number of ranks in output

Tags: sql-server, pivot, rank

I am using the PIVOT function on a SELECT RANK() over(Partition by...) to return a table "matrix" showing which of my war gaming friends have the most wins per army. I want to limit the matrix to only show the top 3 ranked members per army (eg. in the "HE" column in the image below I want to exclude the highlighted record with the rank of "4")

[image: Army Wins by Member]

I presume I need to include a WHERE or TOP clause but cannot determine it's location. I have tried looking on this site and google but cannot find an answer. Sorry if this is a learner's question but I'm still fairly new to SQL Server.

Here are the two tables [Armies] and [Battles] (in spreadsheet format):-
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ana40VqkvVtRdDAwc1BRWnhsWEdaaTQzcFprQmlyeVE

Here's my code:-

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        RANK() over(Partition by ArmyMnemonic Order by COUNT(WDL) desc, Member) as ranks, ArmyMnemonic, Army, Member,
         COUNT(WDL) as Wins
    FROM
        [dbo].[Battles]

    INNER JOIN Armies on Army1 = Armies.ArmyNum

    Where
        WDL=2 and Home=1 -- represents a "Win"
    Group By
        Member, ArmyMnemonic, Army, WDL
    ) as rnk

PIVOT (sum(rnk.ranks) for ArmyMnemonic in([Be],[Br],[DoC],[DE],[Dw],[HE],[Li],[OK],[OG],[Sk],[TE],[TK],[VC],[WoC],[WE])) as pvt

ORDER BY Wins Desc;
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

CREATE TABLE Scripts:-

```
USE [WFBattlesDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Armies]    Script Date: 11/09/2012 13:24:15 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Armies](
[ArmyNum] [int] NOT NULL,
[ArmyMnemonic] [nvarchar](3) NOT NULL,
[Army] [char](30) NOT NULL,
[Official] [bit] NULL,
[Active] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Armies] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

(
    [ArmyNum] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

```
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

---

```
USE [WFBattlesDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Battles]    Script Date: 11/09/2012 13:25:35 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Battles](
[keyBattle] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[subDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Member] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
[Home] [bit] NOT NULL,
[Army1] [int] NOT NULL,
[Army2] [int] NOT NULL,
[WDL] [int] NOT NULL,
[PtsVal] [int] NULL,
[MVU] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[Fun] [int] NULL,
[Luck] [int] NULL,
[Notes] [nvarchar](1500) NULL,
[Link] [nvarchar](255) NULL
```

) ON [PRIMARY]

```
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `ranks` in the `WHERE` clause because it is used in the `PIVOT` function.  So you can create a second `ranks` column, to filter on. I created a second column in the inner select:

```
RANK() over(Partition by ArmyMnemonic Order by COUNT(WDL) desc, Member) as rankFilter
```

You can then use this in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT Army, Member, Wins, [Be],[Br],[DoC],[DE],[Dw],[HE],[Li],[OK],[OG],[Sk],[TE],[TK],[VC],[WoC],[WE]
FROM
(
    SELECT
        RANK() over(Partition by ArmyMnemonic Order by COUNT(WDL) desc, Member) as ranks, ArmyMnemonic, Army, Member,
         COUNT(WDL) as Wins,
       RANK() over(Partition by ArmyMnemonic Order by COUNT(WDL) desc, Member) as rankFilter
    FROM
        [dbo].[Battles]

    INNER JOIN Armies on Army1 = Armies.ArmyNum

    Where
        WDL=2 and Home=1 -- represents a "Win"
    Group By
        Member, ArmyMnemonic, Army, WDL
    ) as rnk

PIVOT (sum(rnk.ranks) for ArmyMnemonic in([Be],[Br],[DoC],[DE],[Dw],[HE],[Li],[OK],[OG],[Sk],[TE],[TK],[VC],[WoC],[WE])) as pvt
where rankFilter <=3

ORDER BY Wins Desc;
```

Or you can apply the `WHERE` in a subquery before the `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT Army, Member, Wins, [Be],[Br],[DoC],[DE],[Dw],[HE],[Li],[OK],[OG],[Sk],[TE],[TK],[VC],[WoC],[WE]
FROM
(
    select *
    from
    (
        SELECT
            RANK() over(Partition by ArmyMnemonic Order by COUNT(WDL) desc, Member) as ranks, ArmyMnemonic, Army, Member,
             COUNT(WDL) as Wins
        FROM
            [dbo].[Battles]

        INNER JOIN Armies on Army1 = Armies.ArmyNum

        Where
            WDL=2 and Home=1 -- represents a "Win"
        Group By
            Member, ArmyMnemonic, Army, WDL
    )  rnk
    where rnk.ranks <= 3
) src
PIVOT (sum(ranks) for ArmyMnemonic in([Be],[Br],[DoC],[DE],[Dw],[HE],[Li],[OK],[OG],[Sk],[TE],[TK],[VC],[WoC],[WE])) as pvt

ORDER BY Wins Desc;
```

Comment: @FranzSigmar please see my edit, there are two ways to perform this filter

Comment: I have just tested it and that works perfectly. Thank you very much @bluefleet, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I've added an extra level of subquerying, so that a simple `WHERE` clause can be applied

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM ( --Subquery start
    SELECT
        RANK() over(Partition by ArmyMnemonic Order by COUNT(WDL) desc, Member) as ranks, ArmyMnemonic, Army, Member,
         COUNT(WDL) as Wins
    FROM
        Battles

    INNER JOIN Armies on Army1 = Armies.ArmyNum

    Where
        WDL=2 and Home=1 -- represents a "Win"
    Group By
        Member, ArmyMnemonic, Army, WDL

    ) t where t.ranks <= 3 --New WHERE clause

    ) as rnk
PIVOT (sum(rnk.ranks) for ArmyMnemonic in([Be],[Br],[DoC],[DE],[Dw],[HE],[Li],[OK],[OG],[Sk],[TE],[TK],[VC],[WoC],[WE])) as pvt
ORDER BY Wins Desc;
```

Comment: I tried but receive this error :- Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
The multi-part identifier "rnk.ranks" could not be bound.

Comment: @FranzSigmar - Could you add table definitions (as `CREATE TABLE` to your question then please?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you cannot call the `rnk.ranks` in the `WHERE` clause because it is used in the `SUM()` area of the `PIVOT`.

Comment: Thanks Damien, this also works perfectly. @blueefeet just beat you to it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all inside another select statement:

SELECT TOP 3 *
FROM (

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        RANK() over(Partition by ArmyMnemonic Order by COUNT(WDL) desc, Member) as ranks, ArmyMnemonic, Army, Member,
         COUNT(WDL) as Wins
    FROM
        [dbo].[Battles]

    INNER JOIN Armies on Army1 = Armies.ArmyNum

    Where
        WDL=2 and Home=1 -- represents a "Win"
    Group By
        Member, ArmyMnemonic, Army, WDL
    ) as rnk

PIVOT (sum(rnk.ranks) for ArmyMnemonic in([Be],[Br],[DoC],[DE],[Dw],[HE],[Li],[OK],[OG],[Sk],[TE],[TK],[VC],[WoC],[WE])) as pvt
```

) data
ORDER BY Wins Desc

Comment: I receive the following error :- Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: I've moved the order by so that it is outside the bracket